# Minecraft Bukkit Api Preventing Player Damage

Tags: api, minecraft, bukkit

im pretty new to bukkit api and I just could not figure out how to prevent player damage. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to prevent players from damaging other entities or prevent the player from taking damage? If you're looking for the latter, do you want the player to be completely invincible or just take damage only from the environment and not entities or vice versa?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A good question would include the description of your efforts. Now it looks like you're just asking for the right code, that's discouraged here. See this helpful article: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how to create a event listener yet. You're going to want to create a new class that implements `Listener`, and register the events for that class in the constructor. Then you need to create an event handler for the `EntityDamageEvent` and cancel the event if its a player. The class should look something like the this:

```
public class MyListener implements Listener { //Implement listener

    public MyListener(){
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, <PLUGIN INSTANCE>) //Register events in the constructor
    }

    @EventHandler //Create a new event handler
    public void onEntityDamage(EntityDamageEvent e){
        if(e.getEntity() instanceof Player){ //Check if the entity is a player
            e.setCancelled(true); //If it is then cancel the event
        }
    }    
}
```

Your also going to have to call the code to register your events while the server is starting up so in the onEnable() of your main plugin class you have to run `new MyListener();`

Comment: Thanks Its Up and Working once again